# Who is the actress playing the school teacher in the first scene of the movie "Children of the Damned" (1964)?

Tags: actor-identification

[image]Does anyone know the name of the actress playing the school teacher in the first scene of the movie *Children of the Damned*? She has a speaking part but doesn't seem to be listed anywhere.
*edit* I got the name of the film mixed up with another. I hope the picture clarifies it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Sci-Fi stackexchange, please make yourself at home. When you're able, please take a look at the [tour] if you haven't already. With regards to your question, have you checked over [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114852/fullcredits)?

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I did check on the imdb and found few actresses, now of which fit the bill. Hence my presence here with you good people. :)

Comment: I think the actress is Sarah Long, but I need more details from you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From checking the [movie-dude](http://movie-dude.com/%5BFilm%5D%20Children%20of%20the%20Damned%20(1963).htm) site, it seems clear that this is [Annette Kerr](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0449645/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1), playing the role of "Scientist", as shown below. "Childen of the Damned" doesn't appear in her CV at IMDB, however, and she is not listed in the cast.

[image]

Comment: For comparison, some shots of Annette Kerr in other movies [here](https://www.aveleyman.com/ActorCredit.aspx?ActorID=19812)--it's definitely her, she looks identical in the shot from "Murder Most Foul" one year later.

Comment: Thank you very much!